# xpath retrieving text inclusive of tag

Tags: xpath

I trying to parse a webpage and get all the content inside a div tag named div1. I tried ('div[@class="div1"]') which gives me the content below

```
  <div class="div1">
                  <p>
                    something something <br>
                    abc<br>
                    def
                  </p>
              </div>
```

However, I am trying to get everything that is inside the div tag, not including the div tag as shown below

```
    <p>
                something something <br>
                abc<br>
                def
              </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your xpath to

```
div[@class="div1"]/child::*
```

Quote from https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths:

> `child::*` selects all element children of the context node

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you're looking for @id when it's @class